# changePage event calls second page as soon as called third page unexpectedly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have three single html pages in jquery mobile application with phonegap. From a page onChange event calls second page. But the second page pageinit called as soon as that page closed and go the third page. I didn't do call for third page in page initialization or some other element.Is it any known issue avialble like this in jquery mobile changepage event?

```
//called from first page link button 
function mysubmit()
{
    $.mobile.changePage("secondpage.html",{reloadPage:true,transition: "none"});
}


//This event fired
$(document).delegate("#secondpage_id", "pageinit", function() {
  alert('secondpage_id was just created by jQuery Mobile!');
});
```

As soon as it fired, it closed the second page and shows third page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Solved by removing `data-rel=back` attribute from first page link button.